# Fix multi-dimensional foo[a][][b] array inputs

Tags: php

I'm using multi-dimensional input tags in my html:

```
Car 1
<input name="warehouse[cars][][name]" />
<input name="warehouse[cars][][model]" />
<input name="warehouse[cars][][year]" />

Car 2
<input name="warehouse[cars][][name]" />
<input name="warehouse[cars][][model]" />
<input name="warehouse[cars][][year]" />
```

The issue with that is that i'm getting some messed up array in the PHP side:

```
Array:warehouse->cars
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Audi,
            [name] => BMW
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [model] => S4,
            [model] => X5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2010
            [year] => 2011
        )

)
```

As you see it's all separated instead of something like:

```
$warehouse['cars'] = array(
 [0] => array(
     'name' => 'Audi',
     'model' => 'S4',
     'year' => '2010'
   )
 ....
)
```

How to fix/re-group this kind of array inputs?

P.S. i know i can do `warehouse[cars][number here][name]` but i prefer not to.

Comment: Well, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: @JaredFarrish What do you mean with "you're out of luck"?

Comment: What you're getting is how that will work. I've run into the same problem before and had to use a numeric index or a key value.

Comment: @ryan because your are using cars][][name] the empty [] will create a new array key for each input thus separating the array. So you need to use keys to get the array setup you would like to create. That is what jared is refering to with his "out of luck" remark.

Comment: The `Array:warehouse->cars(` example is certainly not what you are getting. Duplicate array keys are not possible in a standard php array.

Comment: It's kind've a bummer too, because it would be more elegant, but there's no way for the browser to know those three fields should belong in the same part of the array/that they're related.

Comment: @mario - Yeah, I was thinking that didn't look right. Each `[]` should add a new indexed array member, not group each `name` together, etc. At least, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you reduce the complexity of the arrays, so your code will be easy to debug later. Instead of `warehouse[cars][][name]` and such you can use `cars_names[]`, `cars_models[]` and so on.

So when you read the values you can use smthing like this

```
$j=0;
if(count($_POST['cars_names'])) foreach($_POST['cars_names'] as $car){
    $name = $car;
    $model= $_POST['cars_models'][$j];
    ...
    $j++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting PHP pick out the array keys for you, just specify them explicitly:

```
Car 1
<input name="warehouse[cars][1][name]" />
<input name="warehouse[cars][1][model]" />

Car 2
<input name="warehouse[cars][2][name]" />
<input name="warehouse[cars][2][model]" />
```

Comment: At the very end of the question, @Ryan states he knows this. He's trying *not* to do this.

Comment: Yes, but what the OP wants isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like this:

```
$cars = array(
  'car1', 
  'car2'
);

foreach($cars as $key => $car) {
  echo $car;
  echo '<input name="warehouse[cars]['.$key.'][name]" />';
  echo '<input name="warehouse[cars]['.$key.'][model]" />';
  echo '<input name="warehouse[cars]['.$key.'][year]" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list and regroup the entries:

```
foreach ($_INPUT["warehouse"]["cars"] as $cars) {

    list($key, $value) = each($cars);
    $block[$key] = $value;

    if ($key == "year") {
        $result_list[] = $block;
        $block = array();
    }
}
```

That requires that `year` is really present for all entries.